# how to search Stock ID and Stock No which splites into two columns

Tags: c#

I need to search a stocks by itemNo example: "MG001".

I have created an auto-increment, therefore I have split the `[Stock_ID]` and `[Stock_No]` into two columns in the database table it shows as this:

```
Stock_ID  || Stock_No
---------------------
   1            MG
```

This my gridview table code which merges the `[Stock_ID]` and `[Stock_No]` as `MG001`.

```
private void DisplayData()
{
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand(select_query, conn);
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];

                    string sNo = reader["Stock_No"].ToString();
                    int sId = Int32.Parse(reader["Stock_ID"].ToString());

                    string itemNo = String.Format("{0}{1:D3}", sNo, sId);

                    row.Cells[0].Value = itemNo;
                    row.Cells[1].Value = reader["Gem_Type"].ToString();
                    row.Cells[2].Value = reader["No_of_Pieces"].ToString();
                    row.Cells[3].Value = reader["Weight"].ToString();
                    row.Cells[4].Value = reader["Cost"].ToString();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(reader["Image"] as byte[]);
                    row.Cells[5].Value = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
        conn.Close();
        dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
}
```

This is my search bar code:

```
private void bunifuMetroTextbox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            // use regix 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Stock_Entry Where Stock_No like ('" + bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text + "%') AND Stock_ID like('" + bunifuMetroTextbox1.Text + "%')";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This code is not working please help.

Comment: Are the columns defined in the database as VAR CHAR or Integer?  Do you need a '%" at beginning of the text as well as end?  Are there any spaces in the Textboxes?

Comment: yes the columns are defined in the [Stock_ID] int and [StockNo] nvarchar(15)

Comment: no need a % for both yeh

Comment: there is no spaces in the Textbox

Comment: Remove the WHERE and see if you get a response.  Make sure your response has at least one item that matches the two ids.  Then add one and then the other to see which is causing the issue.